# Can I make eBay API calls from client side with javascript or does that violate the Same-Origin Policy?

Tags: javascript, web, cross-domain, same-origin-policy, ebay-api

For studying I would like to create a simple website including usage of the eBay API. I am currently in the planing process and the following question came up.
"Can I make eBay calls from client side? Does that not violate the Same-Origin Policy (SOP) because its a cross domain request?"

I am a real beginner in Web Development, I guess someone can answer my question fairly easy.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS

Comment: I would look at the eBay API documentation whether they provide ways to circumvent the SOP, either by enabling CORS or providing a JSONP API.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

depending on what API you want to use for example the Finding API supports jsonp,

here a example:

```
// Construct the request
// Replace MyAppID with your Production AppID
var url = "http://svcs.ebay.com/services/search/FindingService/v1";
    url += "?OPERATION-NAME=findItemsByKeywords";
    url += "&SERVICE-VERSION=1.0.0";
    url += "&SECURITY-APPNAME=MyAppID";
    url += "&GLOBAL-ID=EBAY-US";
    url += "&RESPONSE-DATA-FORMAT=JSON";
    url += "&callback=_cb_findItemsByKeywords";
    url += "&REST-PAYLOAD";
    url += "&keywords=harry%20potter";
    url += "&paginationInput.entriesPerPage=3";
```

make sure to set the RESPONSE-DATA-FORMAT to "JSON" and provide a js-callback function via the "callback" param